# Rails ujs - manual AJAX renders HTML template instead of JS template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Products page that has search bar. For every `keyup` I want to update the Product list.

My `index.html.erb` lists ALL products while `index.js.erb` will repopulate the list with the searched product.

The problem is: Rails always returns the **HTML template instead of the JS template**.

So, when I checked the NETWORK tab in Chrome, I get the response but it contains the HTML template.

Here's my simplified code:

```
// js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var query = { search: $(this).val() };
  $.get("/products", query);
});
```

My controller is just a simple `where` clause:

```
# products_controller.rb
def index
  if params[:search]
    @products = Product.where("( LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{ params[:search] }%")
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

The JS template is still an `inspect`

```
// products/index.js.erb
console.log("<%= @products.inspect %>");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a result of showing the `layout` in your `ajax` response:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
Class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      ...
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js   { render layout: !request.xhr? }
         format.json { render json: @products.to_json }
      end
   end
end
```

If you'd like to receive just pure `product` data, you'll want to use `JSON` as follows:

```
$.get("/products", query, dataType: "json");
```

This will give you the ability to receive the json object, which will just be a pure set of data:

```
$.get("/products", query, dataType: "json", function(data){
   //json data will be here
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the `{ render layout: !request.xhr? }` and move the `format.js` above the `format.html` works.